# Body acceptance: is there a gender bias?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology

I tried to google for [female body self esteem statistic](https://www.google.it/search?q=female%2Bbody%2Bself%2Besteem%2Bstatistic&oq=female%2Bbody%2Bself%2Besteem%2Bstatistic&aqs=chrome..69i57.8540j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#). It seem that on a statistic basis women tend to see themselves as not being enough.

I wonder if there are evidence that this problem is related to **social media pressures** and if there is a **gender bias** on body acceptance related especially to **western countries**.

Comment: Perhaps this is a "Western-World" problem due to the western media's ridiculous perception of beauty. Have you checked statistics for other parts of the world?

Comment: @MenaLabib: yes, I've updated the question

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very close: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/12115/are-men-subject-to-optimism-bias-when-it-comes-to-assessing-their-sexual-romanti, and I do cover physical attractiveness in my answer, though not specifically body acceptance.